# Android login and how to make a network blocking call

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-networking

I get a username from a login screen. I want to make a call to a web service to validate user. The problem is that I am getting the error:

`android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`

I know why I'm getting it. I'm making a network call on the main thread.

The problem is that I don't want to use `AsyncTask`. I don't want the user to be able to sign in **BEFORE** I get a response from the web service.

How do I get around this?

Comment: show the login screen after `AsyncTask`  completes the execution.

Comment: If you don't want to use `AsyncTask`, you could also look into using `RxJava` for example, which makes it real easy to offload work to some side thread and get the results back on the main thread.

Comment: you cannot make a network call on main thread. You have to do it asynchronously. Block the UI elements till async task completes.

Comment: nobody forces you to use asynctask, you can use a standard Java Thread, also Url.openConnection() is not async...

Answer (score 1):

You can start an `AsyncTask` when the user opens the first Activity, with a "Waiting" fragment. When the `AsyncTask` finished, you can switch to the "Login" fragment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AsyncTask` as shown below to sign in only when you get a response from the web service.

```
class SignInAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Display a progress bar saying signing in or something
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Call your web service
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // Sign in if the credentials are okay, otherwise show some error message to the user
    }
}
```

If you really don't want to use `AsyncTask` you could start a new Thread and put your logic here.

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {

    public void run() {
        // Sign in validation
    }
}).start();
```